# Expected expression before >> token

Tags: c, token

```
 if (cross(s, t))>>0{
  printf("turns to the left\n");
} else if (cross(s, t))==0{
  printf("points are co-linear\n");
} else (cross(s, t))<<0 {
  printf("turns to the right\n");
}
```

I have declared the cross function earlier, any help would be great!

Comment: Check your parentheses.

Comment: You know `>>` is shift right. You want `>=` which is greater than or equal to.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `cross` returns `int`, you have the closing brackets in the wrong place in your conditions

```
if (cross(s, t))>>0{
```

should be

```
if (cross(s, t)>>0){
//                ^
```

etc.

Also, as noted by Jeff Mercado, if you want to test for less than / equal to / greater than zero, you should use `<`, `==`, `>` respectively.

Using `>>` or `<<` performs a bitwise shift; this leave a test that bit shifts zero places then returns true for any non-zero answer.  This presumably isn't what you want.

Comment: Furthermore, I think he wants to compare greater or less than zero. Shifting 0 either way does nothing.

Comment: @JeffMercado Thanks, good point.  I've updated my answer to cover this

Answer (score 1):

`if` statements look like this:

```
if(condition) {
}
```

yours is:

```
if condition {
}
```

You need to replace your parenthesis:

```
if (cross(s, t)>>0)
```

Looking at your code..it kind of seems like you might want a

```
if(cross(s,t) > 0)
```

`>>` is known as a [bit shift](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/bitshift.html) which might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: I got it fixed! the structure wasn't right for an if statement, i was using the wrong operators and trying to assign types to different types! thanks

Comment: @user2945892 Great! If you got it fixed please put a green check mark next to the answer you found helpful so this question can be marked as solved!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want '>>' and '<<' which are bit shifting operations. You want '<' and '>' :

```
if (cross(s, t)>0){
  printf("turns to the left\n");
} else if (cross(s, t))==0{
  printf("points are co-linear\n");
} else (cross(s, t)<0) {
  printf("turns to the right\n");
}
```

Note that parentheses must be around the whole expression, too

Answer (score 0):

An if statement has the format

```
if ( _condition-expression_ ) _expression_
```

Your condition expression best approximately matches

```
_condition-expression_ <==> cross(s, t)
```

And the `>>0{` is not a valid opening of an expression.  To fix this, you need

```
_condition-expression_ <==> cross(s, t) > 0
```

which would make the if statement resemble

```
if (cross(s, t) > 0) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use just a single > or < if you want to check if a left-operand is higher or lower than a right-operand, the double << and >> are bitwise operators